# Passing value by pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

As far as I'm concerned I'm passing the variables spoilt and valid through to the function Proccosvotes correctly, but I'm not getting the right answer. Instead of incrementing valid by 1 like I thought I was doing, it's adding random numbers to it. For instance, I should be getting around 200 for valid, but I'm getting 2687468. I can seem to find the error. Does anyone see or know the mistake I'm making?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct election{
    char name[20];
    int votes;
};

struct election electionCandidates[7];

void Initialize(struct election electionCandidates[], int num, FILE *ifp);
void Processvote(struct election electionCandidates[], int num, FILE *ifp, int *valid1, int *spoilt1);

int main(){
    FILE *ifp;
    char *winner[20]; 
    int valid = 0;
    int spoilt = 0;
    int num;

    ifp = fopen("elections.txt", "r"); 

    Initialize(electionCandidates, 6, ifp);

    Processvote(electionCandidates, 6, ifp, &valid, &spoilt); 

    system("PAUSE");

    printResults(electionCandidates, 6, &valid, &spoilt, *winner); 


    printf("GO");
    system("PAUSE");

    fclose(ifp);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void Initialize(struct election *electionCandidates, int num, FILE *ifp){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
        fscanf(ifp, "%[^\n]%*c", &electionCandidates[i].name);
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, electionCandidates[i].name);
    }
}

void Processvote(struct election *electionCandidates, int num, FILE *ifp, int *valid1, int *spoilt1){
    int i;
    int x=0;
    int j;
    for(i=0; i<365; i++){
        fscanf(ifp, "%d ", &x);

        for(j=1; j<=7; j++){
            if (j == x){
                electionCandidates[j].votes+=1;
                valid1++;
            }  

            if (x < 1 || x > 7)
                spoilt1++;                  
        }
        printf("valid: %d\nspoilt: %d\n", valid1, spoilt1);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Inside `Processvote`, `valid1` and `spoilt1` have type `int *`, not plain `int`. `valid1++` does not do what you think it does, and neither does `printf("%d...", valid1...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem 1

In C, arrays start counting at 0 not 1.

Therefore, the following code will cause **undefined behavior**, because you call `electionCandidates[7]`.

```
    for(j=1; j<=7; j++){
        if (j == x){
            electionCandidates[j].votes+=1;
```

#### Problem 2

`spoilt1` and `valid1` are pointers to single integers. If you want to use the value that the pointer is pointing to, then you should do things like:

```
printf("%d", *spoilt1);
*spoilt1 += 1;
```

#### Problem 3

You're missing the implementation of `printResults()`, so I'm not sure how you're running this at all.

#### Problem 4

Your compiler **should** be printing out a few warnings for this code. At the very least, you should fix them. Note that warnings are often indicative of a real problem in your code that you shouldn't ignore. Here's the warnings and errors that my compiler reports:

```
[11:53am][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] clang foo.c
foo.c:30:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printResults' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printResults(electionCandidates, 6, &valid, &spoilt, *winner); 
    ^
foo.c:45:34: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat]
        fscanf(ifp, "%[^\n]%*c", &electionCandidates[i].name);
                     ~~~~        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.c:66:43: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("valid: %d\nspoilt: %d\n", valid1, spoilt1);
                       ~~                 ^~~~~~
foo.c:66:51: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("valid: %d\nspoilt: %d\n", valid1, spoilt1);
                                   ~~             ^~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_printResults", referenced from:
      _main in foo-1d49c9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

#### Problem 5

You should check that your calls to `fscanf()` actually succeed. If the file is short or otherwise invalid, you might not update the value of your variables.

Comment: alright, i fixed the first two problems. For problem 3, I have the implementation in my actual code, but I meant to take all of that out because I don't actually have any code running within the printResults function. And the weird thing is, I'm running my code in Dev C++, and it's not bringing up any of those warnings. So, I'll try to fix them based off of what you posted. Thanks

Comment: Once, I included parentheses like: `(*spoilt)++` it worked. =] Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In Processvote, valid1 has the type pointer to an integer.  In you code you write `valid1++`, which is incrementing the value of the pointer, not what it is pointing to.  Try `(*valid1)++` and also `(*spoilt1)++`

Comment: Interesting, I ran it without the parentheses and nothing changed, but when I included the parenthese like you have, it fixed the 'valid' value. Then I took the `if (x < 1 || x > 7){spoilt1++;}` and moved it out of the second for loop and it works perfectly. =] Thank you!

Comment: Check out operator precedence (for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), notice that suffix increment is higher precedence then dereference, so *valid1++ is equivalent to *(valid1++).